# Пожалуйста, помогите решить задачу!

Tags: python

заменить 3 самых частых символа на 3 самых редких. (предполагается, что в строке есть как минимум 6 различных символов различной частоты)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Встроенные функции для строк ```max()```, ```min()```, ```replace()``` и ```translate()``` - это все, что вам нужно для решения этой задачи. Изучите их и продвинетесь в решении. Даже циклы необязательны.

Answer (score 1):

1. с помощью `collections.Counter` получить список `{символ: кол-во}`
2. преобразовать в список `(символ, кол-во)`
3. отсортировать
4. в цикле от 0 до 2 заменить через `replace` частые символы на редкие

Comment: Можно ```translate``` вместо ```replace```, тогда цикл не нужен.